# Start up of of tomcat 6 on server when windows starts

Tags: tomcat6

I have already a running web application on my server, the thing is that I want tomcat to start when windows starts. I have already gone to the windows services and looked for tomcat but i could not find Apache tomcat as a service there. What should I do to make it start when windows starts?
Anteneh

Answer (score 0):

Install it as a service.

See the steps here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html

Comment: Thanks Andres, since I have a running application I don't want to uninstall my current tomcat but is there a way to put the current one as windows service?

Comment: Do it with service.bat. Take a look at this blog: http://digitalcrop.blogspot.com.es/2012/01/install-tomcat7-on-windows-with-zip.html

Comment: Thanks Andres, actually I have solved the problem by downloading and installing tomcat from this link 
http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi and picked
32-bit/64-bit Windows Service Installer (pgp, md5)  from core section of the page...